# java final array lowercase or uppercase

Tags: java, arrays, variables, final

I understand that clean code convention requires that final variables be ALL_CAPS in Java. But what if my variable is an array? Must it be all caps? As in which one of the following is best practice:

```
public static final String[] MY_ARRAY = {"A", "B"};
//...
String str = MY_ARRAY[0];
```

Or

```
public static final String[] myArray = {"A", "B"};
//...
String str = myArray[0];
```

Comment: I'm not sure that the type of variable will matter, if it was final I would still use MY_ARRAY to know that it was final.

Comment: This is a primarily opinion-based question.

Comment: You should use `myArray` as it's not immutable (and public so alterable from other classes).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No Java code conventions that I'm aware of advocates that *all* final variables should be all caps. *Constants* should be all caps, and by constants you usually refer to final fields that are immutable (or deliberately never mutated).

In this case you're using an array, and since it public it may very well be mutated. For this reason, I wouldn't count this as a constant, and therefor go with `myArray`.

For reference, here's a quote from the Official Oracle Java Code Conventions:

> The names of variables declared class constants and of ANSI constants should be all uppercase with words separated by underscores (“_”). (ANSI constants should be avoided, for ease of debugging.)

Comment: Thank you so much. So if the variable were `private` then it would be `MY_ARRAY`?

Comment: If it's private and you don't mutate it, then yes, that would qualify as a constant and suitable to name in all caps.

Comment: **final** has to do with the reference and not with the object.